Emma plays a game with rocks
Emma is playing a game. She has to place rocks on a $3\times3$ square board such that rocks are placed on non-adjacent squares (squares that are not directly above, below, left, or right of another square).
(a) How many ways are there for Emma to place 4 rocks on her $3\times3$ board?
(b) How many ways are there for Emma to place 3 rocks on her $3\times3$ board?
(c) Emma changes to a $5\times5$ board, keeping the same rock placement rules as before. How many ways are there for Emma to place 11 rocks on this $5\times5$ board?
I tried finding all the possible ways of placing the rocks on $3\times3$ board but extending it to a $5\times5$ board seems complicated.
For (a), I thought that there were $6$ positions on a $3×3$ board (the four corners and the center), where rocks can be placed such that they are not adjacent to each other. Since Emma needs to place exactly 4 rocks, it is merely a matter of selecting $4$ out of these $5$ positions, which can be done in $5$ different ways but there are also the middle squares of the sides.
I'm not sure if this method is correct. Any hints/help will be appreciated.

Let the board be $n×n$ and you've to place $k$ rocks on the board....solve this and then substitute $n$ and $k$ accordingly

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad but the rocks can only be placed on non-adjacent squares

@Ekarshi you should leave the answer here since maybe someone can correct it

See e.g. https://oeis.org/A006506 and https://oeis.org/A232569 and the links therein.

@R.J.Mathar so what would the answer for (b) and (c) be?

https://oeis.org/A232833 is the sequence containing the actual answers.

It doesn't give any hints on nice ways to compute elements, though.

@aschepler I can't seem to find the answer for (b) in the sequence

My count of $21$ was incorrect.

@aschepler is it 22 for (b)? https://oeis.org/A201511

Alternatively color the square board (like a chessboard) in Black & White ($B$ & $W$)
Since $n$ in $n × n$ is odd, do it such that all $4$ corner-most squares are $B$
For a $3 × 3$ board, $5$ squares will be $B$ and $4$ will be $W$
Notice that all same-colored squares are non-adjacent to each other
For (a), we have to select $4$ non-adjacent squares
We find that in any such selection, all the $4$ squares will be of the same color
This is because if we select $1B$ , atleast $2W's$ will be blocked (exactly $2$ will be blocked if we choose $B$ present at the corner), leaving us with only $2W's$ which are not sufficient for $4$ squares
Likewise, we observe that selecting $2B's$ will block atleast $3W's$ (exactly $3$ will be blocked if we choose $2B's$ present in same peripheral row/column), leaving us with only $1W$ which is not sufficient for $4$ squares

In general, choosing $kB's$ will block atleast $(k+1)W's$

Inspired from this answer
So $4$ non-adjacent squares can be selected in $C(5,4)+C(4,4) = 6$ ways (all $B$ or all $W$)
For (b), if the $3$ non-adjacent squares are of the same color, they can be selected in $C(5,3)+C(4,3)=14$ ways
Also, you can select any one of the corner $B$ (in $C(4,1)$ ways). After doing so, only $2W's$ non-adjacent to it will be left. So in total, there are $4$ selections of the type $BWW$
Also, you can select $2$ corner $B's$ from each peripheral row/column, and you'll be left with only $1$ non-adjacent $W$ wrt to them, so number of $BBW$ selections is $4$
Final answer for (b) is $14+4+4=22$
For (c), color a $5×5$ board in the same way (all $4$ corner squares as $B$). So $13$ squares are $B$ & $12$ are $W$
Now, if all $11$ rocks are placed on same-colored squares, it can be done in $C(13,11)+C(12,11)=90$ ways
If $kB's$ are selected, they'll block atleast $(k+1)W's$. So at max $12-(k+1)=(11-k)$ $W's$ will be left (exactly what we require)
Select $1B$ from one of the $4$ corner squares (in $C(4,1)$ ways), then you'll be left with exactly $10$ non-adjacent $W's$. So we get $4$ selections of the type $1B,10W$
Select $1W$ from the $2W's$ present in each peripheral row/column (in $C(2,1)×4$ ways). You will be left with exactly $10$ non-adjacent $B's$. So we get $8$ selections of the type $1W,10B$
We observe that for greater selections $(>1)$ of $B's$ or $W's$, less than $10$ non-adjacent $W's$ & $B's$ (respectively) are left
So final answer of (c) is $90+4+8=102$
Edit: Saw one of the comments below, I guess I missed out a case. Thanks for reminding
We can also select $2W's$ adjacent to each of the $4$ corners $B's$. They'll block $4$ $B's$ leaving us with $9$ non-adjacent $B's$. So $4$ more cases $(2W,9B)$
Correct Answer for (c) is $102+4=106$

By my computer program, and by https://oeis.org/A232833, part (c) is 106. Not sure where you missed some.

$9B,2W$, where the blacks fill a triangle along two edges of the board and including the diagonal between them, and the whites are on the two spaces adjacent to the remaining corner.

Thanks! I just figured it out now

By the way, is there a concrete method to solve it for larger values of $n$?

Seems hard. If a way were known, likely this OEIS sequence or a closely related one would note that. If you find one, you can submit a comment to OEIS, probably even publish a paper!

Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm just a high-schooler right now. I don't know any programming (the only program I've ever written is print "hello world")

As shown in https://oeis.org/A232833, there are 22 ways to arrange 3 rocks on a 3x3 board,
There are 6 ways to arrange 4 rocks on a 3x3 board.
There are 276 ways to arrange 3 rocks on a 4x4 board.
There are 405 ways to arrange 4 rocks on a 4x4 board.
Now lookin in detail into https://oeis.org/A232833/b232833.txt :
There is 1 way to arrange no rock on a 5x5 board.
There are 25 ways to arrange 1 rock on a 5x5 board.
There are 260 ways to arrange 2 rocks on a 5x5 board.
There are 1474 ways to arrange 3 rocks on a 5x5 board.
There are 5024 ways to arrange 3 rocks on a 5x5 board.
There are 2578 ways to arrange 9 rocks on a 5x5 board.
There are 618 ways to arrange 10 rocks on a 5x5 board.
There are 106 ways to arrange 11 rocks on a 5x5 board.
The C++ program to show them all is
/*
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4897017/emma-plays-a-game-with-rocks?noredirect=1#comment10450788_4897017
*/
#include <iostream>
class A232833
{
public:
        int n ;
        int k ;
        A232833(int nside, int n1s) : n(nside), k(n1s)
        {
        }

        void show(const short *board, int piv)
        {
                for(int r=0 ; r < n ; r++)
                {
                        for(int c=0 ; c < n ; c++)
                        {
                                if ( c+n*r < piv)
                                        std::cout << board[c+n*r] ;
                                else
                                        std::cout << '.' ;
                        }
                        std::cout << std::endl ;
                }
                std::cout << std::endl ;
        }

        long long count(short *board, const int piv, const int kleft)
        {
                long long ct=0 ;
                const int c = piv % n;
                const int r = piv / n ;
                bool can1(true) ;

                //show(board,piv) ;
                if ( kleft == 0)
                        can1 = false ;
                else
                {
                        /* check value up, r-1,c */
                        if ( r > 0)
                        {
                                const short up= board[c+(r-1)*n] ;
                                if ( up > 0)
                                        can1 = false ;
                        }
                        /* check value left, c-1,r */
                        if ( c > 0)
                        {
                                const short up= board[c-1+r*n] ;
                                if ( up > 0)
                                        can1 = false ;
                        }
                }
                short onemax = can1 ? 1 : 0 ;

                for(short one =0 ; one <= onemax ; one++)
                {
                        board[c+n*r] = one ;
                        /* next to the right or new row
                        */
                        if ( piv+1 < n*n)
                        {
                                ct += count(board,piv+1,kleft-one) ;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                /* complete */
                                if ( kleft-one ==0 )
                                {
                                        ct =1 ;
                                        show(board,piv+1) ;
                                }
                        }
                }
                return ct ;
        }

        long long count()
        {
                short *board = new short[n*n] ;
                for(int i=0 ; i< n*n ; i++)
                        board[i] =0 ;
                long long ct= count(board,0,k) ;
                delete [] board ;
                return ct ;
        }
protected:
private:
} ;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int n = atoi(argv[1]) ;
        int k = atoi(argv[2]) ;
        A232833 board(n,k) ;
        long long ct = board.count() ;
        std::cout << n << " " << k << " " << ct << std::endl ;
}
```

